# Discount label and code variable

Tags: discount, coupon, variables

I am trying to create custom variable in Magento, but how do I get the discount label for the code used and variable for discount description.

I have found the following code, but am not sure how to get the correct field from the database.

```
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByCode('custom_variable_code')->getValue('text');
```

also do I use the variables in this format?

```
{{var custom_variable}}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea, what you mean with "discount label" and "discount description" in this context, but to answer the question, how to use custom variables,
your codes already are correct:

- the first code is PHP, you can use it in the phtml templates or in PHP classes.
- the second code is a CMS directive that you can use in CMS pages, static blocks and email templates.